# python f'string not working in pd.Series.map function

Tags: python, pandas, format, series, f-string

I have a pd series,

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])
```

when I do,

```
s.map('this is a string {}'.format)
[out]
0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3    this is a string nan
```

how can I get the same result by using formatted string?

```
s.map(f'this is a string {?}') ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use lambda function with [`{x}`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498):

```
print (s.map(lambda x: f'this is a string {x}'))
#alternative with different value
#print (s.map(lambda val: f'this is a string {val}'))
0    this is a string 1.0
1    this is a string 2.0
2    this is a string 3.0
3    this is a string nan
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution is possible without `map` / `apply` + `lambda`. You can assign a list directly to a series. A list comprehension is often more efficient since [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) is not vectorised:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])})

df['t'] = [f'this is a string {i}' for i in df['s']]

print(df)

     s                     t
0  1.0  this is a string 1.0
1  2.0  this is a string 2.0
2  3.0  this is a string 3.0
3  NaN  this is a string nan
```